# Keep a total count of each column's count in each row

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having a hard time researching this because it's hard to put it into a question, I've got a database that is similar to this:

```
| id | user | clicks | keys |
| -- | ---- | ------ | ---- |
| 1  | test | 3      | 4    |
| 2  | usah | 5      | 9    |
```

I would like to get the totals quickly(It shouldn't have to count them every time) like this:

```
| clicks | keys |
| ------ | ---- |
| 7      | 13   |
```

I don't have a problem adding clicks and keys to a row designed to store the totals, but `what is the best way to store a single row that won't have its id changed`, and how would I go about getting the initial totals from the already-existing database?

My original approach was to create another table the a suffix of _total or something, and just grab the first row, but that seems overkill to me. Would adding a row and naming it something specific like this be the best way?:

```
| id | user   | clicks | keys |
| -- | ------ | ------ | ---- |
| 3  | TOTALS | 3      | 4    |
```

Comment: If you need this to be really fast, you can use something like redis that stores key value pairs of data for this kind of stuff

Comment: If you must save this data somewhere, go with your initial, "overkill", design. Otherwise you will sooner or later wish you had done this! Imagine having to exclude `user='TOTALS'`every time you need to query your original table for something other than the totals...

Comment: How large is your table, and how often would you want to access this total?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis the totals would be the first thing loaded on the web page, the user totals would be secondary, so essentially every time the page loads

Comment: I see; so you may want to have them materialized, in which case I suggest a different table.